# Hide Multiple Woocommerce shipping methods from logged out users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i am trying to hide multiple shipping methods from logged out users and for some reason my code doesnt work, so please help, here is my code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_methods_based_on_wholesale_customer', 10, 2 );
function shipping_methods_based_on_user_status( $rates, $package ){
    $is_loggedout = !is_user_logged_in());
    
    // Set the shipping methods rate ids in the arrays:
    if( $is_loggedout ) {
        
    } else {
        $shipping_rates_ids = array('flat_rate:10', 'flat_rate:11', 'flat_rate:12', 'flat_rate:13'); // To be removed for loggedout users
    }

    // Loop through shipping rates fro the current shipping package
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( in_array( $rate_key, $shipping_rates_ids) ) {
            unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); 
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the conditions, You code is checking the logged-in users right now. The code should be like below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_methods_based_on_wholesale_customer', 10, 2 );
function shipping_methods_based_on_user_status( $rates, $package ){

    // Check if logged out ( not logged in )
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        
        // Set the shipping methods rate ids in the arrays:
        $shipping_rates_ids = array('flat_rate:10', 'flat_rate:11', 'flat_rate:12', 'flat_rate:13'); // To be removed for loggedout users
        
        // Loop through shipping rates fro the current shipping package
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if ( in_array( $rate_key, $shipping_rates_ids) ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); 
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
```

(Not tested)